# Deleting Last Character From a String in Java

Tags: java, string, char, jpasswordfield

I'm writing a java code which gives an error when typing more than 10 characters in a PasswordField and cannot type from there on. I tried deleting the last character from the PasswordField on a KeyPressed event but instead of deleting the last character, it deletes the character before it and replace it with the last character.Here goes my code.

private void passFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
String pw1 = new String(passField.getPassword());
    
    if(passField.getPassword().length==10){

        try{

          StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer(pw1);
           bf.deleteCharAt(10);
          String pw2 = new String(bf);    
           passField.setText(pw2);
                             
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><h4>Password Must Not Contain More Than 10 Characters !</h4></html>", "Error !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

           }

        catch(Exception e){
            
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

I'm still a newbie for programming. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks !

Comment: Use a `DocumentFilter` instead. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166921/how-to-set-documentfilter-with-input-length-and-range-e-g-1-3-or-10-80/15168429#15168429), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937207/jtextfield-set-input-limit/29937259#29937259), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458047/remove-last-character-from-jtextfield/27458525#27458525), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416006/limit-the-amount-of-characters-typed-into-a-jtextfield/25416046#25416046)

Comment: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136794/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-jtextfield/24473097#24473097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to delete a char from the String.

You can use the **StringBuilder** class here to delete a character at your specified position. First convert your String to **StringBuilder** -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
```

Then you can use the built in method `deleteCharAt()` to delete the char at your desired position like this -

```
sb.deleteCharAt(10);
```

*Hope this may help you.*

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RemoveChar {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
              String str = "India is my country";  
              System.out.println(charRemoveAt(str,));  
           }  
           public static String charRemoveAt(String str) {  
              return str.substring(0, str.length()-1);  
           }  
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but Linga Lgm Cse's code does output exactly the same output as mine.. ;'(

Answer (score 0):

Guys I'm so sorry I found out it was a mistake of mine..I actually had to check the length of the passwordfield again and length must be 11 to delete the 10th character. Here goes the code.It worked..Thanks for helping guys !!!!!!!!

private void passFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
String pw1 = new String(passField.getPassword());
    
    if(passField.getPassword().length==11){

        try{

          StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer(pw1);
           bf.deleteCharAt(10);
          String pw2 = new String(bf);    
           passField.setText(pw2);
                             
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><h4>Password Must Not Contain More Than 10 Characters !</h4></html>", "Error !", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

           }

        catch(Exception e){
            
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```